# How do I compare a text array of values against a nested JSONB object that contains data I need to SUM?

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to do some queries/calcs on an existing database for a game and I'm not super familiar with postgres and json data access. Even being green, I realize that this data is not stored in anything close to an optimal format. I have only read access to this data, and it is not mine to optimize or reorder.

PostgreSQL 15.2

As a bit of context:

The game is a turn-based game where players are on one of two teams and set up "shots" on a grid, battle-ship style.

I have a users table with 'uid' (text) and 'games' (text[]) columns. These "games" ids indicate unfinished and finished games that the user (uid) is associated with.

| uid | games |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | [12, 14, 17] |
| 4312 | [56, 57, 59] |

I also have a finished_games table with 'game_id' (integer) and 'playbook' (jsonb) columns. There are many game ids, each representing a "finished" or settled game that is now static and completely concluded.

| game_id | playbook |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | jsonbdata |
| 14 | jsonbdata |

A user's 'games' array is a list of all game_id's that user has ever been associated with. Some are finished and some are ongoing.

Here's an example of the sort of json data stored under "playbook":

```
{
  "seed": "blah",
  "players": [
    {
      "uid": "0x6blah",
      "username": "dianaprince",
      "game_plan": {
        "attack": [
          {
            "value": "C5"
          },
          {
            "value": "A2"
          },
          {
            "value": "B2"
          },
          {
            "value": "C8"
          }
        ],
        "defend": [
          {
            "value": "C7"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": "0xBblah",
      "username": "brucewayne",
      "game_plan": {
        "attack": [
          {
            "value": "B6"
          },
          {
            "value": "C7"
          },
          {
            "value": "A9"
          },
          {
            "value": "C9"
          }
        ],
        "defend": [
          {
            "value": "A4"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "gameplay": [
    {
      "seed": "blah",
      "team1": [
        {
          "uid": "0x6blah",
          "dead": false,
          "kills": 0
        }
      ],
      "team2": [
        {
          "uid": "0xBblah",
          "dead": false,
          "kills": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seed": "blah",
      "team1": [
        {
          "uid": "0x6blah",
          "dead": false,
          "kills": 0
        }
      ],
      "team2": [
        {
          "uid": "0xBblah",
          "dead": false,
          "kills": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "team1": [
        {
          "uid": "0x6blah",
          "dead": true,
          "kills": 0
        }
      ],
      "team2": [
        {
          "uid": "0xBblah",
          "dead": false,
          "kills": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, "kills" are stored per uid (with a value of n for the turn; in other words, it's not a running total for the game, but rather PER TURN) and then that data is per team (out of two possible teams) and then that data is per round, which is then under "gameplay".

I need to create a query that gives me all 'uid's in "users" and then gives me a total number of "finished games" that user took part in as well as a number of "total kills in all finished games".

If I just knew how to properly do one of these, I think I could figure out the other. This is just a bit above my current skill level and I need to learn.

Assuming 'users u' and 'finished_games fg' ...

I tried variations on various JOINs between users and finished_games ON an overlap operator between u.games and fg.playbook (and a million different ways of querying into that json, which is where I became lost). I've also tried a monster subquery chain to get this data with incorrect results due to my own inexperience and logic errors or misunderstanding of how to properly drill down into the json data.

My last attempt was to unpack the fg.playbook using a jsonb_path_query, but set-returning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions. My query structure is hopelessly incorrect.

What I'm EXPECTING would be a result set like this:

| uid | finished_kills | games_participated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 |
| Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

with uid being a text uid, finished_kills containing an int with the number of kills for that uid within all finished_games, and with games_participated containing an int with the number of games that uid is associated with from ONLY the finished_games table (vs the "u.games" list of ALL games regardless of whether they are finished).

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple and straightforward and a great example to show why it is a good idea to store foreign keys in arrays and tabular data in nested JSON objects:

```
WITH k AS (
   SELECT f.game_id,
          c.u ->> 0 AS uid,
          count(*) AS kills
   FROM finished_games AS f
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(
                            f.playbook,
                            'strict $.**[*] ? (@.kills == 1).uid'
                         ) AS c(u)
   GROUP BY f.game_id, c.u ->> 0
)
SELECT u.uid, k.kills
FROM users AS u
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(u.games) AS g(game_id)
   JOIN k
      ON u.uid = k.uid
         AND g.game_id::integer = k.game_id;
```

The common table expression extracts the `uid` of all objects where `kills` is 1 and joins that with `finished_games`, the main query extracts all `game_id`s from the `users` table and joins with the CTE. The power of JSONPATH makes it possible.

Comment: Laurenz, you rock! 

I'm going to go over this with a fine-toothed comb and learn from it so I can set up some similar queries that I need. This also answered some other, semi-unrelated query structure questions I had rattling around my head. 

Thank you again, this was super helpful.

Comment: If I wanted to add in the second part of that query where I calculate the total number of finished games associated with each uid in the same result set, would I just need to create another CTE and then join that result with the main query as well to show both values in the same final results set?

Comment: For example, I imagine it would look something like this addition just below your first CTE: 
M AS (
  SELECT g.game_id,
  c.u ->> 0 AS uid,
  count(*) AS total_games
 FROM finished_games AS f
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(
        f.playbook,
        'strict $[*] ? uid'
  ) AS c(u)

GROUP BY f.game_id, c.u ->> 0
)

I'm still reading through the documentation for json_path_queries, so please forgive my incorrect path above.

Comment: These additional questions are too complicated to think through at the moment. But I am sure you can build upon what is there.

Comment: Reading through this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html leads me to believe that this CTE + jsonpath would be very close to what I need, but it gives me a 'syntax error at end of jsonpath input"

m AS (
 SELECT f.game_id,
   c.u ->> 0 AS uid,
   count(*) AS total_games
 FROM finished_games AS f
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(
       f.playbook,
       'strict $.players[*].uid ? (@ == uid)'
      ) AS c(u)
 GROUP BY f.game_id, c.u ->> 0
)

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, totally understandable.  

I'll keep fiddling with it!

Comment: Sorry to ping you again, but I wanted to let you know why I changed my acceptance of your answer. 

After actually digging into the results of your bare, original query and verifying the data, I can see that it's actually incorrect. None of the "kills" data derived by your query seem to line up with the actual number of hand-counted kills per player. The format is incorrect as well, with multiple copies of given "uid"s being displayed with all incorrect kill counts. 

I've removed your answer as the "solution", but I appreciate your help and time earlier all the same!

Comment: I had to go with your description and guess the rest. I guessed that you are interested in the entries with `"kills": 1`, and that the difference in the `uid` was a mistake.

Comment: You did great and it's no fault of yours! I appreciate your help and I learned quite a bit from your query. 

Once I resolve this satisfactorily I'll add my own solution.